# Text input doesn't work in QML

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I have a simple TextInput element, but I can't type anything in it.

```
import QtQuick 1.0


Rectangle{
    width: 100
    height: 100

    TextInput{
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        text: '234'
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you test your code and which version of Qt are you using? When I'm running it in qmlviewer, I can easily edit the text in the TextInput.

Comment: I'm using PySide, Qt 4.7

Comment: If you're using QML inside PySide, could you provide the relevant Python part of the code, too?

Comment: Do you see the "234"?